# how to take input with while loop so that it discards old input in every x seconds?

Tags: javascript

I am writing an application that has to take audio input of a certain frequency range and increase the counter variable till clock ticks x seconds after the browser starts taking the input. I have done most of it but the problem is the loop with input. for example if I want to take frequency level 10 or above, and write following code

```
    if (f>10) {
      var count=0;
      count++;
    }
```

the code increases count only once. But I want to increase it based on the sound til x seconds. If I use while loop the scripts stops responding.

Comment: what does your while-loop look like? what do you expect from the piece of code you pasted anyway?

Comment: I want to increase the count variable til 4 seconds. so if the browser detects frequency >10 in between 4 seconds 2 times, the counter value should be equal to 2.

Comment: please edit your post instead of writing in the comments. It looks terrible.

Comment: @dingalapadum sorry about that. Actually I explained about it in the next comment. So I deleted that part. well, it was not working by the way. It was just a try.

Comment: getting Audio input is not an issue here, issue is taking the input in every x seconds and increase the count variable. so I need a loop that can take 4 seconds (for example) as condition and within that loop I can execute the code I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is synchronous. You'll need to use an asynchronous loop. You have a couple options for this:

1. Use a setTimeout and put your while loop in that and use a callback when it gets finished
2. Use a setInterval.

---

```
var loop = function(f, callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var count=0;
    while(f>10){
      count++;
    }
    callback(count);
  }, 0);
};
```

or

```
var loop = function(f, callback){
  var count = 0;
  var si = setInterval(function(){
     count++
     if(f<=10){
         clearInterval(si);
         callback(count);
     }
   }, 1000);

};
```

---

Using these functions:

```
loop(frequencyVariable, function(count){
   //callback has been called successfully and the loop has ended.
   //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: well, at least its not working here. I dont see the count variable increases. and frequency variable is declared in another function. so I tried to declare it in here and run. But no luck.

Comment: if your frequency variable is not being declared globally then either add it as a parameter to your loop function or **window.f = f;**

Comment: if I put console.log(count); it does not show me anything about count.